# ASP.Net List box iPhone/Android mobile issue

Tags: iphone, asp.net

This might be an issue with the way Safari and Android browsers render a list box, but is there a way around it? We have a listbox control that shows available times for events. The times are dynamically shown from a database and fed to the listbox.

Android and iPhones make the scrollable listbox a drop list box.  You know the one with the arrow on the right and shows everything from the droplist.  Or in the HTML it renders a list box as a select box with `<option>` tags.

Is there a way to override that issue.
CSS, Javascript, anything?

Comment: Same problem for me - tried to replace ListBox with ListView, but I cannot activate row selection. In addition, mobile preview in desktop version of Edge, Chrome and Firefox incrorrectly displays the listbox, while in an Android device/emulator a dropdown appears. Is it a bug in mobile preview, in ALL browsers??!