# ASP.Net Listbox Empty on Android and iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, asp.net

I created a small web site, with a ASP.Net Listbox(.Net 4.0).

When I acces the site from My computer using either Chrome og IE10, it Works fine. When i open it on Ipad, Iphone or My samsung Galaxy s3 (Android 4.0.3) the listbox appears empty, however when i click i can see the possible options to select. Is there anyway to make the visible at all times like on my computer ?

Comment: In term of HTML, a ListBox is represented with a <select> ?

Comment: i dont understand ? im not that good with HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882859/asp-net-list-box-iphone-android-mobile-issue

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. I fixed it by replacing Listbox with Listview.

Comment: I tried to replace ListBox with ListView, but I cannot activate row selection. Can you please share further info on your solution?

Comment: Hi @johnnyontheweb it has been a while when I worked on this issue. If you have some environment that I could check your code, I can try to provide you some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Hartok it's font color issue. you just try to change font color may be  it will solved